# How to bind a Scrollbar to Canvas when using python TKinter to create GUI?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

Well, I want to create a GUI with python via Tkinter method. Here is the question, I have managed to bind a scrollbar to the Canvas, but the scrollbar doesn't work, it can't control the content existing in Canvas, it's useless. would anyone here probably help me fix the problem? I'd like to appreciate your help and the time you would spend. and below it's the original code.

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title('Bit Exraction')
root.geometry('800x600')
cv_frameindex=  ['CV_F0','CV_F1','CV_F2','CV_F3','CV_F4','CV_F5','CV_F6','CV_F7','CV_F8','CV_F9','CV_F10','CV_F11','CV_F12','CV_F13','CV_F14','CV_F15','CV_F16','CV_F17','CV_F18','CV_F19',\
      'CV_F20','CV_F21','CV_F22','CV_F23','CV_F24','CV_F25','CV_F26','CV_F27','CV_F28','CV_F29','CV_F30','CV_F31','CV_F32','CV_F33','CV_F34','CV_F35','CV_F36','CV_F37','CV_F38','CV_F39',\
      'CV_F40','CV_F41','CV_F42','CV_F43','CV_F44','CV_F45','CV_F46','CV_F47','CV_F48','CV_F49','CV_F50','CV_F51','CV_F52','CV_F53','CV_F54','CV_F55','CV_F56','CV_F57','CV_F58','CV_F59',\
      'CV_F60','CV_F61','CV_F62','CV_F63','CV_F64','CV_F65','CV_F66','CV_F67','CV_F68','CV_F69','CV_F70','CV_F71','CV_F72','CV_F73','CV_F74','CV_F75','CV_F76','CV_F77','CV_F78','CV_F79'
      ]

 GPIO_index=['GPIO-0','GPIO-1','GPIO-2','GPIO-3','GPIO-4','GPIO-5','GPIO-6','GPIO-7','GPIO-8','GPIO-9','GPIO-10','GPIO-11','GPIO-12','GPIO-13','GPIO-14','GPIO-15','GPIO-16','GPIO-17','GPIO-18','GPIO-19',\
      'GPIO-20','GPIO-21','GPIO-22','GPIO-23','GPIO-24','GPIO-25','GPIO-26','GPIO-27','GPIO-28','GPIO-29','GPIO-30','GPIO-31','GPIO-32','GPIO-33','GPIO-34','GPIO-35','GPIO-36','GPIO-37','GPIO-38','GPIO-39',\
      'GPIO-40','GPIO-41','GPIO-42','GPIO-43','GPIO-44','GPIO-45','GPIO-46','GPIO-47','GPIO-48','GPIO-49','GPIO-50','GPIO-51','GPIO-52','GPIO-53','GPIO-54','GPIO-55','GPIO-56','GPIO-57','GPIO-58','GPIO-59',\
      'GPIO-60','GPIO-61','GPIO-62','GPIO-63','GPIO-64','GPIO-65','GPIO-66','GPIO-67','GPIO-68','GPIO-69','GPIO-70','GPIO-71','GPIO-72','GPIO-73','GPIO-74','GPIO-75','GPIO-76','GPIO-77','GPIO-78','GPIO-79'
      ]

 bak_index=['bak0','bak1','bak2','bak3','bak4','bak5','bak6','bak7','bak8','bak9','bak10','bak11','bak12','bak13','bak14','bak15','bak16','bak17','bak18','bak19',\
      'bak20','bak21','bak22','bak23','bak24','bak25','bak26','bak27','bak28','bak29','bak30','bak31','bak32','bak33','bak34','bak35','bak36','bak37','bak38','bak39',\
      'bak40','bak41','bak42','bak43','bak44','bak45','bak46','bak47','bak48','bak49','bak50','bak51','bak52','bak53','bak54','bak55','bak56','bak57','bak58','bak59',\
      'bak60','bak61','bak62','bak63','bak64','bak65','bak66','bak67','bak68','bak69','bak70','bak71','bak72','bak73','bak74','bak75','bak76','bak77','bak78','bak79'
      ]
 for i in range(80):
     bak_index[i]=[]


 t1=Frame(root,height=1,width=300)
 Label(t1,text='Use:  1-GPIO       O-Native\n',anchor='w',height=2,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
 t1.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

 t2=Frame(root,height=1,width=300)
 Label(t2,text='I/O:  1-Output     O-Input\n',anchor='w',height=2,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
 t2.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

 t3=Frame(root,height=1,width=300)
 Label(t3,text='H/L:  1-High       O-Low\n',anchor='w',height=2,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
 t3.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

 t4=Frame(root,height=1,width=300)
 Label(t4,text='INV:  1-Invert     Input Value\n',anchor='w',height=2,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
 t4.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

 t5=Frame(root,height=1,width=300)
 Label(t5,text='Pin Default Set As Native Function\n',anchor='w',height=2,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
 t5.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

 t6=Frame(root,height=0,width=300)
 Label(t6,text='--'*90,anchor='w',height=1,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
 t6.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)



 t7=Frame(root,height=5,width=300)
 tt=Frame(t7,height=1,width=300)
 lb1=Label(tt, text='PIN',height=1,width=20,anchor=W).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
 lb2=Label(tt, text='  USE',height=1,width=20,anchor=W).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
 lb3=Label(tt, text='         I/O',height=1,width=20,anchor=W).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
 lb4=Label(tt, text='               H/L',height=1,width=20,anchor=W).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
 lb5=Label(tt, text='  INV',height=1,width=20,anchor=CENTER).pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
 tt.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)
 tt1=Frame(t7,height=1,width=300)
 Label(tt1,text='--'*90,anchor='w',height=1,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
 tt1.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)
 t7.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

 cv=Canvas(root,height=30,width=30, scrollregion=(0,0,40,800),bg='red')
 S1=Scrollbar(cv,orient='vertical',command=cv.yview)
 cv['yscrollcommand']=S1.set
 S1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
 cv.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y, expand=True)

 for j in range(80):
     cv_frameindex[j]=Frame(cv, height=10, width=10)
     bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=GPIO_index[j], height=1, width=13, anchor=CENTER))
     bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=' '*20, height=1, width=10, anchor=CENTER))
     bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='0', state='active'))
     bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='1', state='active'))
     bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=' '*20, height=1, width=13, anchor=CENTER))
     bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='0', state='active'))
     bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='1', state='active'))
     bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=' '*20, height=1, width=13, anchor=CENTER))
     bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='0', state='active'))
     bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='1', state='active'))
     bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=' '*20, height=1, width=13, anchor=CENTER))
     bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='0', state='active'))
     bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='1', state='active'))
     bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=' '*20, height=1, width=13, anchor=CENTER))
for k in bak_index:
    for i in range(len(k)):
        k[i].pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
for L in cv_frameindex:
    L.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)

t8=Frame(cv, height=5, width=300)
Button(t8, text='Generate').pack(fill=Y)
t8.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)

t9=Frame(cv, height=5, width=300)
Button(t9, text='Generate').pack(fill=Y)
t9.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The posted code has indentation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scrollbar attached to a canvas will only scroll items that are *in* the canvas. Using `pack` or `grid` doesn't place an object *in* the canvas. To do that you must use `create_window` method of the canvas.

If you want to create a scrolling frame, you should put all of your labels and checkbuttons in a frame, then add that single frame to the canvas with `cv.create_window(...)`. There are several examples of how to do that on this site and elsewhere.

Unfortunately, just doing that won't make your code work. You have other errors, such as the fact you aren't having the canvas expand in the X direction, so it will only be 30 pixels wide.

I've adjusted your code to work; play close attention to all of the lines of code related to `inner_frame`:

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title('Bit Exraction')
root.geometry('800x600')
cv_frameindex=  ['CV_F0','CV_F1','CV_F2','CV_F3','CV_F4','CV_F5','CV_F6',
                 'CV_F7','CV_F8','CV_F9','CV_F10','CV_F11','CV_F12','CV_F13',
                 'CV_F14','CV_F15','CV_F16','CV_F17','CV_F18','CV_F19','CV_F20',
                 'CV_F21','CV_F22','CV_F23','CV_F24','CV_F25','CV_F26','CV_F27',
                 'CV_F28','CV_F29','CV_F30','CV_F31','CV_F32','CV_F33','CV_F34',
                 'CV_F35','CV_F36','CV_F37','CV_F38','CV_F39','CV_F40','CV_F41',
                 'CV_F42','CV_F43','CV_F44','CV_F45','CV_F46','CV_F47','CV_F48',
                 'CV_F49','CV_F50','CV_F51','CV_F52','CV_F53','CV_F54','CV_F55',
                 'CV_F56','CV_F57','CV_F58','CV_F59','CV_F60','CV_F61','CV_F62',
                 'CV_F63','CV_F64','CV_F65','CV_F66','CV_F67','CV_F68','CV_F69',
                 'CV_F70','CV_F71','CV_F72','CV_F73','CV_F74','CV_F75','CV_F76',
                 'CV_F77','CV_F78','CV_F79']

GPIO_index=['GPIO-0','GPIO-1','GPIO-2','GPIO-3','GPIO-4','GPIO-5','GPIO-6',
            'GPIO-7','GPIO-8','GPIO-9','GPIO-10','GPIO-11','GPIO-12','GPIO-13',
            'GPIO-14','GPIO-15','GPIO-16','GPIO-17','GPIO-18','GPIO-19','GPIO-20',
            'GPIO-21','GPIO-22','GPIO-23','GPIO-24','GPIO-25','GPIO-26','GPIO-27',
            'GPIO-28','GPIO-29','GPIO-30','GPIO-31','GPIO-32','GPIO-33','GPIO-34',
            'GPIO-35','GPIO-36','GPIO-37','GPIO-38','GPIO-39','GPIO-40','GPIO-41',
            'GPIO-42','GPIO-43','GPIO-44','GPIO-45','GPIO-46','GPIO-47','GPIO-48',
            'GPIO-49','GPIO-50','GPIO-51','GPIO-52','GPIO-53','GPIO-54','GPIO-55',
            'GPIO-56','GPIO-57','GPIO-58','GPIO-59','GPIO-60','GPIO-61','GPIO-62',
            'GPIO-63','GPIO-64','GPIO-65','GPIO-66','GPIO-67','GPIO-68','GPIO-69',
            'GPIO-70','GPIO-71','GPIO-72','GPIO-73','GPIO-74','GPIO-75','GPIO-76',
            'GPIO-77','GPIO-78','GPIO-79']

bak_index=['bak0','bak1','bak2','bak3','bak4','bak5','bak6',
           'bak7','bak8','bak9','bak10','bak11','bak12','bak13',
           'bak14','bak15','bak16','bak17','bak18','bak19','bak20',
           'bak21','bak22','bak23','bak24','bak25','bak26','bak27',
           'bak28','bak29','bak30','bak31','bak32','bak33','bak34',
           'bak35','bak36','bak37','bak38','bak39','bak40','bak41',
           'bak42','bak43','bak44','bak45','bak46','bak47','bak48',
           'bak49','bak50','bak51','bak52','bak53','bak54','bak55',
           'bak56','bak57','bak58','bak59','bak60','bak61','bak62',
           'bak63','bak64','bak65','bak66','bak67','bak68','bak69',
           'bak70','bak71','bak72','bak73','bak74','bak75','bak76',
           'bak77','bak78','bak79'
      ]
for i in range(80):
    bak_index[i]=[]


t1=Frame(root,height=1,width=300)
Label(t1,text='Use:  1-GPIO       O-Native\n',anchor='w',height=2,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
t1.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

t2=Frame(root,height=1,width=300)
Label(t2,text='I/O:  1-Output     O-Input\n',anchor='w',height=2,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
t2.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

t3=Frame(root,height=1,width=300)
Label(t3,text='H/L:  1-High       O-Low\n',anchor='w',height=2,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
t3.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

t4=Frame(root,height=1,width=300)
Label(t4,text='INV:  1-Invert     Input Value\n',anchor='w',height=2,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
t4.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

t5=Frame(root,height=1,width=300)
Label(t5,text='Pin Default Set As Native Function\n',anchor='w',height=2,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
t5.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

t6=Frame(root,height=0,width=300)
Label(t6,text='--'*90,anchor='w',height=1,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
t6.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)


t7=Frame(root,height=5,width=300)
tt=Frame(t7,height=1,width=300)
lb1=Label(tt, text='PIN',height=1,width=20,anchor=W).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
lb2=Label(tt, text='  USE',height=1,width=20,anchor=W).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
lb3=Label(tt, text='         I/O',height=1,width=20,anchor=W).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
lb4=Label(tt, text='               H/L',height=1,width=20,anchor=W).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
lb5=Label(tt, text='  INV',height=1,width=20,anchor=CENTER).pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
tt.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)
tt1=Frame(t7,height=1,width=300)
Label(tt1,text='--'*90,anchor='w',height=1,width=300).pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
tt1.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)
t7.pack(side=TOP,fill=Y)

cv=Canvas(root,height=30,width=30, scrollregion=(0,0,40,800),bg='red')
S1=Scrollbar(root,orient='vertical',command=cv.yview)
cv['yscrollcommand']=S1.set
S1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
cv.pack(side=TOP, fill="both", expand=True)

inner_frame = Frame(cv, background="pink")
cv.create_window(0, 0, anchor="nw", window=inner_frame,tags=("frame",))

for j in range(80):
    cv_frameindex[j]=Frame(inner_frame, height=10, width=10)
    bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=GPIO_index[j], height=1, width=13, anchor=CENTER))
    bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=' '*20, height=1, width=10, anchor=CENTER))
    bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='0', state='active'))
    bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='1', state='active'))
    bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=' '*20, height=1, width=13, anchor=CENTER))
    bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='0', state='active'))
    bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='1', state='active'))
    bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=' '*20, height=1, width=13, anchor=CENTER))
    bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='0', state='active'))
    bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='1', state='active'))
    bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=' '*20, height=1, width=13, anchor=CENTER))
    bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='0', state='active'))
    bak_index[j].append(Checkbutton(cv_frameindex[j], text='1', state='active'))
    bak_index[j].append(Label(cv_frameindex[j], text=' '*20, height=1, width=13, anchor=CENTER))

for k in bak_index:
    for i in range(len(k)):
        k[i].pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
for L in cv_frameindex:
    L.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)

t8=Frame(inner_frame, height=5, width=300)
Button(t8, text='Generate').pack(fill=Y)
t8.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)

t9=Frame(inner_frame, height=5, width=300)
Button(t9, text='Generate').pack(fill=Y)
t9.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)

def on_configure(event):
    cv.itemconfigure("frame", width=event.width)
    cv.configure(scrollregion=cv.bbox("all"))

# make sure the inner frame is always as wide as the canvas,
# and that the scrollregion is up-to-date
cv.bind("<Configure>", on_configure)

root.mainloop()
```

Since you are apparently building a grid of widgets, you might want to consider using the `grid` geometry manager instead of `pack` for everything in the inner frame. It will save you from having to create a bunch of extra frames, and is specifically for doing grid-based layouts.

Also, if you want a horizontal separator, you can use a frame with a height of 2 and a borderwidth of 2, instead of a label with a bunch of dashes in it.

Finally, if you are using two checkbuttons to represent only the two numbers 0 or 1, you can use a single checkbutton. Checkbuttons have an `onvalue` and `offvalue` attribute which defines the value when the button is checked or not.

Comment: would you please tell me how to put all of the labels and checkbuttons in a frame without changing the format that I expected? since I have tried it following your suggestion but all of the items were displayed in one row, I have no idea how to put them in a single frame but in different rows. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @clement_lei: create one new frame that is a child of the canvas. Then, instead of `cv_frameindex[j]=Frame(cv, height=10, width=10)`, do `cv_frameindex[j]=Frame(the_new_frame, height=10, width=10)`.  That will cause everything to be packed into the new frame rather than into the new canvas. Then, you'll need to do `cv.create_window(..., window=the_new_frame)` to put the frame into the canvas so that it can be scrolled. You'll have to set the scrollregion of the canvas, and you might have to manage the width of the frame so that it is exactly the width of the canvas.

Comment: Forgive me a Python beginner. I did it as you told me:                                                                    cv=Canvas(root,height=800,width=300, scrollregion=(0,0,100,800),bg='red')

FF=Frame(cv, height=800, width=300)
for j in range(80):
    cv_frameindex[j]=Frame(FF,height=10,width=10) ....... then  cv.create_window(800,300, window=FF,anchor="nw")   but I can't see any items except the scrollbar. Please give me one more help!thanks.

Comment: @clement_lei: I've updated my answer to have a working example based on your code.

Comment: Mr.Oakley, I really appreciate your kind help! good example for my python study. Again, thanks a lot.